# Run Apache Hadoop 2.7.0 in Microsoft Windows 8.1

Tags: maven, hadoop, sdk, hadoop2

First, I download the latest version of Hadoop Apache 2.7.0-src.tar.gz
Second, I decompressed it and move it to C. 
Then I used this SDK 7.1 command line:

```
 hdfs>mvn package -Pdist,native-win -DskipTests -Dtar
```

This is the output I got :

```
 Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus/3.3/
 plexus-3.3.pom
 Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus/3.3/p
 lexus-3.3.pom (20 KB at 525.2 KB/sec)
 Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-si
 nk-api/1.0/doxia-sink-api-1.0.pom
 Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-sin
 k-api/1.0/doxia-sink-api-1.0.pom (2 KB at 39.8 KB/sec)
 Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia/1.
 0/doxia-1.0.pom
 Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia/1.0
 /doxia-1.0.pom (10 KB at 241.5 KB/sec)
 Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-parent/1
 0/maven-parent-10.pom
 Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-parent/10
 /maven-parent-10.pom (31 KB at 594.1 KB/sec)
 *
 * 
 * 
 Many Lines of download files.
 *
 [ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
 [ERROR]
 [ERROR]   The project org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-main:2.7.0 (C:\hdfs\pom.xml) has
 7 errors
 [ERROR]     Child module C:\hdfs\hadoop-project\pom.xml of C:\hdfs\pom.xml does not exist
 [ERROR]     Child module C:\hdfs\hadoop-assemblies\pom.xml of C:\hdfs\pom.xml does not exist
 [ERROR]     Child module C:\hdfs\hadoop-maven-plugins\pom.xml of C:\hdfs\pom.xml
  does not exist
 [ERROR]     Child module C:\hdfs\hadoop-yarn-project\pom.xml of C:\hdfs\pom.xml
 does not exist
 [ERROR]     Child module C:\hdfs\hadoop-mapreduce-project\pom.xml of C:\hdfs\pom.xml
  does not exist
 [ERROR]     Child module C:\hdfs\hadoop-tools\pom.xml of C:\hdfs\pom.xml
 does not exist
 [ERROR]     Child module C:\hdfs\hadoop-dist\pom.xml of C:\hdfs\pom.xml 
 does not exist
 [ERROR]
 [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the 
 -e switch.
 [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
 [ERROR]
 [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions,
 please read the following articles:

 [ERROR] [Help 1] 
 http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildin
 gException
 C:\hdfs>
```

I don't know how to fix this problem. I have pom file but it's in the home directory. Do I need to copy and paste it in each of the above files?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the issue as reported on

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2717426

> To resolve this issue, you must uninstall all versions of the Visual
>   C++ 2010 Redistributable before installing the Windows 7 SDK.  You may
>   have one or more of the following products installed:
>
> - Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 x86 Redistributable
> - Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 x64 Redistributable
>
> After uninstalling the Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable products, you may install the Windows 7 SDK.

Answer (score 0):

It states that the Pom.xml file is missing. Try to use new packages as by below link  ,

http://bfeinsilver.blogspot.com.es/2014/03/installing-apache-hadoop-220-on-windows.html

Please use the steps to build the Apache Hadoop.